# How to center align a particular contact form 7 in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using contact form 7 plugin in Wordpress.
I have two forms but I want to center align only one.

I have added this code in my additional CSS

```
div.wpcf7 {
text-align: center;
}
```

But it Works but on both the forms

The one I want to center align has this shortcode

```
[contact-form-7 id=”257″ title=”Subscription Form”]
```

I used to simply type `<center>`at the starting of the shortcode. 
But I now I am using a plugin to customize the form.
It just asks to select the form which you want to customize instead of typing shortcode.
But it is not center aligning the text.
so, please tell me the code for additional CSS to align text or complete form in the center BUT ONLY ONE FORM NOT ALL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Howard-E points out, Contact Form 7 will name the form `wpcf7-f<form ID>-p<integer>-o<integer>`. You can target the form with ID 257 using the `^=` starts with selector:

```
[id^="wpcf7-f257"] { /* styles here */ }
```

```css
[id^="wpcf7-f257"] {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f257-xyz">
This should be centered
</div>

<div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f258-xyz">
This should not be centered
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou so much.
I just copied

 [id^="wpcf7-f257"] {
  text-align: center;
}


And I saw the magic 
Just that form got in center NOT others.

BTW dont have or know page ID. Anyway IT WORKED :) yay !!

Comment: Man you solved my problem. I am not a coder but I sometimes need coding help. So If text me on WhatsAPP or something that would be great. I will send you a couple of dollars everytime you solve my little coding problems. WhatsApp me on +919354109153? My Facebook -https://www.facebook.com/digirishab

Comment: I’m glad it worked! I suggest you keep posting your code questions here at Stackoverflow. That way others with similar issues may benefit as well! :o)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to look at the id, which is unique for each form.  The ID will contain your form ID (257) and the page ID - whatever that is.  In the example below, it's page id 12.  You will have to find your own.

```
<div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f257-p12-o1" lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
```

Once you have that info, put it in your CSS.

```css
div#wpcf7-f257-p12-o1 {
   text-align: center
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you set everything align to center , you have to SET width:100% and display:block to all elements.

Try :

```
.wpcf7 input , .wpcf7 label {
  width:100%;
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
}
```